# Display mysql data in formatted table

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving data from a database and displaying in a table. I would like the table to be in a 4 x 3 layout. The data retrieves just fine, it's the layout that isn't working.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ezwayautos');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
    echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td height='160' valign='top' class='featured'>";
    echo "<div class='Image-Thumbnail'>";
    echo "<a href=''>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."' width='160' height='54'>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div> <a href=''>" .$row['vehicle_name']. "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

What is supposed to go in each cell is a picture of the vehicle with the name underneath the picture.

Here is an example from another website as to how I would like it to look:

http://www.denisonmotors.com

I am not stealing any information from their site I am just trying to get my data to display in the format that they have on their site.

I am not concerned about the empty href tag as they will be filled in later.

**After doing some research, I think that I have to use 2 for loops to create the table stating how many columns and row that I want.**

Comment: the last 3 lines in the loop should be outside of it

Comment: @Dagon You keep beating me to the punch by seconds, still my excuse is I had to format some code

Comment: @RiggsFolly luckly i enjoy a good beating

Comment: Tommy you are going to have to show us an example of what you are after then

Comment: we need to know what goes into what cells. You should be precise when it comes to questions like this. The "what"'s are which rows from your query etc. edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it explains it better.

Comment: You should really look at using an MVC framework such as laravel, its so messy to mix view and controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Is it as simple as moving the last 3 lines that close the outer table outside the while loop?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ezwayautos');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td height='160' valign='top' class='featured'>";
    echo "<div class='Image-Thumbnail'>";
    echo "<a href='inventory/view/7995179/2005-Volvo-XC90-4dr-2.html'>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."' width='160' height='54' alt='".$row['vehicle_name']."'>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div> <a href='inventory/view/7995179/2005-Volvo-XC90-4dr-2.html'>" .$row['vehicle_name']. "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: if it's of any comfort @Dagon I upvoted your comment, but then took it away and gave it to Smokey.

Comment: he meant BOSCH. He's quite a spark. We shall name him *Sparky*

Comment: I'm sure Sparky won't mind ;-) don't ya Sparky?! @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

The table generation is not correct. I think you don't mean to create a table inside another table, so I think this is the way you should do:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td height='160' valign='top' class='featured'>";
    echo "<div class='Image-Thumbnail'>";
    echo "<a href='inventory/view/7995179/2005-Volvo-XC90-4dr-2.html'>";
    echo "<img src='".$row['image']."' width='160' height='54' alt='".$row['vehicle_name']."'>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div> <a href='inventory/view/7995179/2005-Volvo-XC90-4dr-2.html'>" .$row['vehicle_name']. "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

You have to create the table once, and then a row for each record.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions and am still getting the display going from top to bottom instead of a 4 x 3 for meaning 4 cells across by 3 cells down