# Php echo in table and with css

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have the following code:

```
<div id="Container">
<div class="tester">
<table>
<tr><th class="links"><span style="color: #ffd100">MYSQL DATA</span></th></tr>
<tr><th class="links">MYSQL DATA</th></tr>
<tr><th class="links">MYSQL DATA</th></tr>
<tr><th class="links">MYSQL DATA</th></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want the variables "MYSQL DATA" out of my mysql with php echo. I have the conncetion to the database but i don´t know where to insert the echo $row->name; etc.

```
<?php 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXX","XXXXXX") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
    mysql_select_db("XXXXXX") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

  $abfrage = "SELECT `name` FROM `TEST`"; 
  $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) 
    { 

    echo $row->name; 
    echo $row->id; 

 }

}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo out table rows from the db (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970936/how-to-echo-out-table-rows-from-the-db-php) **Or** [Display mysql data in formatted table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236830/display-mysql-data-in-formatted-table)

Comment: Depends on the structure, you could generate the tables via the `while`-loop that fetches data from the database. None the less, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and removed entirely in PHP 7) and you shoud [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Example with mysqli and echo th with php:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="tester">
        <table>
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXXXX","XXXXXX") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
mysqli_select_db($link, "XXXXXX") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

$abfrage = "SELECT `name` FROM `TEST`"; 
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($link, $abfrage);
$i=0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)) 
{
    if ($i === 0) { ?>
<tr>
    <th class="links">
        <span style="color: #ffd100"><?php echo $row->name; ?></span>
    </th>
</tr>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
    <td class="links"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentation (english and german):

[mysqli connect (en)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[mysqli select db (de)](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.select-db.php)

[mysqli query (de)](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php)

[mysqli fetch object](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Same as above. The mysql data doesn´t appear. If i do a normal query without table and styles it works.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
<div id="Container">
<div class="tester">
<table>
<tr>
<th>
name
</th>
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXX","XXXXXX") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
mysql_select_db("XXXXXX") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

$abfrage = "SELECT `name` FROM `TEST`"; 
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) 
{ ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="links"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This creates all rows as [table header cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th). (I know the op's code is like that, but it's worth mentioning ^^)

Comment: just change the th to td and add row before the while with table headers that you want

Comment: i edit it to make them td :) with th before thanks for mention FirstOne

Comment: Thanks for this code. I tried it out, but the mysql data doesn´t appear for some reason.

Comment: Nothing, just the <th>name</th> and the div container.

Comment: are you sure there is result from your sql ?

Comment: i just re-arrange your code i didn't add anything :(

Comment: If i just do a simple query, everything works. `<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect ("localhost",
"XXXXX", "XXXXXX")
or die ("keine Verbindung möglich.
 Benutzername oder Passwort sind falsch");

mysql_select_db("XXXXX")
or die ("Die Datenbank existiert nicht.");


$abfrage = "SELECT name FROM TEST";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
   {
   echo "$row->name";
   }
?> `

Answer (score 0):

You should save this as `.php` not `.html`

```
<div id="Container">
<div class="tester">
<table>
<?php 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXX","XXXXXX") or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
    mysql_select_db("XXXXXX") or die ("Datenbank existiert nicht");

  $abfrage = "SELECT `name` FROM `TEST`"; 
  $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis)){ 
   if($row[0])
      echo '<tr><th class="links"><span style="color: #ffd100">'.$row->name.'</span></span></th></tr>';
   else
       echo '<tr><th class="links">'.$row->name.'</span></th></tr>';
  }

?>
</table>
</div>
```